i7-1355U or R7-7730U As a Plex Media Server?
I have been picking between...
Requirements:

I hate noise so i need it to be fanless

It will be a 24/7 Plex server

It needs to be able to transcode 4K HDR videos - Score higher than 17000

I will install Ubuntu onto it

i can use it for other purposes like a Jenkins server for minor tasks


R7-7730U

Product page: https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=760455801898

For some reasons its way cheaper (~CNY1000 cheaper)

Benchmark screen is higher than requirement - Scored 18854


i7-1355U

Product page: https://item.taobao.com/item.htm?id=725959349017

Benchmark screen is lower than requirement?! - Scored 15255

I heard it's safer to pick Intel as Plex supports it better - LINK


Which one should i pick??
